# Does mobile application needing offline sync implicitly involve duplicate business logic?

Tags: android, asp.net, .net, web-services

I am developing a mobile application which needs to run (to a useable limit) even if the user is offline but should also save everything in the server.

The approach I have finalized is this -

1. Write the business logic in client except the unavoidable ones like authorization.
2. Synchronize the data from client to server periodically.

This entails duplicating the business logic everywhere, in android, in ios and in web service although its going to be much easier if I could write the business logic in the web service.

How can I achieve offline syncing without duplicating business logic. What are the best practices around it? How do applications like whatsapp do it?

Comment: Are you concerned about duplicating logic between different OSes or between client/server?  The latter can be solved with a component-oriented architecture.

Comment: In my case, I am going to have the business logic duplicated in the different OSs and also in the web service which is being consumed by the web application. Without the offline syncing in picture the web service was being consumed by all clients giving a very neat architecture but I need the offline syncing for faster and always on performance.

Comment: Also @DStanley could you please elaborate on your component-oriented architecture approach?

Comment: Build smaller components (e.g. assemblies in .NET) that can be re-used by both client and server.  That doesn't help your cross-OS development problem, though.

Comment: I am working on an exact same application like you described. I use mvc api calls and Microsoft Sync Framework for database synchronization. And to answer your question there would definitely be overlap across cross platform if you are going to do it natively.